# apache2.2 on mint 15 - getting forbidden 403

Tags: linux, permissions, apache2

I am running mint 15 on my desktop.

I am trying to set up a make-shift media server for roksbox so I can view movies in my bedroom via my roku player.

I downloaded apache2.2 and I am running a localhost out of /var/www/

I created a folder in /var/www/media

I created a symlink in /media to my external hdd where my movies are /var/www/media/Movies

The problem is that when I go to my browser and type in localhost/media it shows nothing. If I type in localhost/media/Movies it says: forbidden 403

I checked the error logs and it says the symlink cannot be found or client does not have permission to access it.

I went into /etc/apache2 and edited my default-000 file in my enabledsites folder and added:

```
<directory /var/www/media >
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MulitViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</directory>

<directory /var/www/media/Movies >
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MulitViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</directory>
```

I also changed the permissions in my /var/www folder with chmod x+o and in my media folder with a -R

all folders show root permissions

www-data is the default user group but I didn't try (again) to get all the folders into that workgroup - they are just at the default usergroup which is my user for linux. I did however aadd myself to the www-data workgroup just in case.

Now I've tried a few other things but I'm at an loss here. I think I might be doing the permissions incorrectly. Anyone have any ideas?

(I'm doing this from work so I don't have the log files handy)

I do have one idea - since my hdd is external and its being access from root directory /media/ could that be the problem?

also I turned off selinux and my home folder is encrypted (just fyi)

Answer (score 0):

**I do have one idea - since my hdd is external and its being access from root directory /media/ could that be the problem?**

I'd be pretty certain that is exactly the issue - everything else looks okay. I've experienced similar using Plex on Linux with external HDD's and shared partitions.

When you get home run:

```
ls -la /media/
```

....and see if root is the owner of the HDD or not. You'd be better off changing the owner + group to your user if root is the owner.

```
chown -R user:group /media/Movies
```

Then for permissions my bet is to run:

```
find /media/Movies -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find /media/Movies -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Lastly you may need to add www-user to your user group since your user will then be the owner. Pretty sure that's just:

```
usermod -G <group> <user>
```

Good luck!